# Decrease ORMlite's internal log verbosity or disable it

Tags: android, logging, logcat, logback, ormlite

We're doing some heavy performance tuning in our app, hence we start using method tracing to find the bottlenecks.

At first glance Ormlite was fine, but we found that for example in one query that takes 8ms, 6ms (75%) were needed by Ormlite's internal log. Futhermore those log call are in DEBUG level.

At the moment I have tried (without success) setting log level to ERROR this way:

- with adb: `adb shell setprop log.tag.ORMLite ERROR`
- with logback:  `<logger name="com.j256.ormlite" level="ERROR"/>`

This are a few lines from the logcat

```
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,702 [DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement query-for-id using ...
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,706 [DEBUG] StatementExecutor executing raw query for ...
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,709 [DEBUG] SelectIterator starting iterator  @-1593957304 for ...
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,711 [DEBUG] SelectIterator closed iterator @-1593957304 after 1 rows
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,714 [DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement query-for-id using ...
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,717 [DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement query-for-id using ...
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,718 [DEBUG] StatementBuilder built statement ...
I/System.out( 4207): 2014-10-01 10:50:14,719 [DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement prepared statement ...
```

Here is a screnshot of method tracing

[image: ORMLite method tracing]

Any thoughts on how to handle this out?

Comment: So by default Android is in INFO log mode.  Are you saying that ORMLite was spitting out DEBUG messages even at this level?   Or was this a performance problem with the DEBUG log messages even though they were not being displayed?

Comment: Just for others, ORMLite's docs about Android logging are here: http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging

Comment: @Gray I added some extra info, What is strange is that logcat output appears as Info (I/Sytem.out) but the tag used is debug ([DEBUG])

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With method tracing we saw that LocalLog was being used. As is stated on [LocalLog's](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/logger/LocalLog.html) documentation:

> You can set the log level by setting the System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, 
>   "trace").
>   Acceptable values are: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL.

We couldn't set the property using `adb shell` so we added the following line to our `Application.onCreate`

```
System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, "ERROR");
```

Finally we stop seeing ORMLite output on logcat and performance increased as expected.

Comment: Huh.  I'm not sure why the LocalLog was being used under Android.  It's a fallback only.  I'll add this to the Android logging docs @Axxiss.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gray Perhaps is because we use ormlite in a pure java library being imported into an Android project. I'm just guessing.

Comment: This happens then you use ProGuard. Since there is no direct usage of logger classes ProGuard strips them all away, and so there is only LocalLog which is referenced directly in library code. I experienced the same, and got all loggers around only after tuning ProGuard rules.

Comment: It seems it is "WARNING" and not "WARN" the acceptable value

Answer (score 1):

For me I used ORMLite in my project (not with android). there I used the logback.xml to configure it.

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html

> If that class is not found it then looks for org.apache.log4j.Logger
>   and if found will use Log4j.

So we can simply use logback.xml as bellow.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.my.test" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, we already had ormlite configured with that file but it completely ignored the log level as far as I remember.

Comment: There is an order. 
"The logger code first looks for the android.util.Log and if found will use the Android internal logger"

If you are doing android related work, android.util.Log would be the best place to configure.

Answer (score 0):

ORMLite documentation on Android mentions how to enable the logs over adb: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Android-Logging

However, there's no mention how to disable them.
From @Axxiss answer, we can see the proper log level is `ERROR`.
Thus, to disable the logs using adb:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.StatementExecutor ERROR
adb shell setprop log.tag.BaseMappedStatement ERROR
adb shell setprop log.tag.MappedCreate ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set log level directly for `com.j256.ormlite` package in the `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] [%X{worker_name}] [%logger{36}/%method\(%line\)] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- log level for ORMLite -->
    <logger name="com.j256.ormlite" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- log level for your application -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ormlite uses DEBUG level

Set the desired level with the code:

```
import com.j256.ormlite.logger.Level;
com.j256.ormlite.logger.Logger.setGlobalLogLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).