# Remove logs from ORMLite Android

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to remove all logs from ORMLite in production, such as:

`TableUtils: creating table ...`

I tried the following:

```
System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, "ERROR");
System.setProperty("log.tag.ORMLite", "ERROR");
System.setProperty("log.tag.DaoManager", "ERROR");
System.setProperty("log.tag.TableUtils", "ERROR");
System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_FILE_PROPERTY, "log.out");
```

Is there something that I'm missing?   I need a solution without proguard.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrease ORMlite's internal log verbosity or disable it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128874/decrease-ormlites-internal-log-verbosity-or-disable-it)

Comment: @thepoosh not a duplicate, since I tested their solution and it did not work...