# How to disable android ORMLite log

Tags: android, ormlite

I have read this [post about decreasing ORMlite's log verbosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128874/decrease-ormlites-internal-log-verbosity-or-disable-it), it gives the solution

> System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, "ERROR");

Unfortunately, it fails in my case, there still prints the ormlite log in logcat. I have debug into the source code, find it have a complex log-logic. But still, I find the ormlite uses the ***com.google.code.microlog4android.Logger*** component to print trace instead of the Androidlog, which ignores the value I set via System.setProperty.

Has anyone met this issue? Why does it use microlog (We imported the microlog component, does it relate to this?)? How to disable the log?

Comment: why does my post downgrade?

Comment: I've upvoted but your question would be better if it stood on it's own.  I.e. don't reference another post.  You can talk about another problem but you should define your problem here completely.

Comment: ok，i see....what I want to say is that solution not works for me and wonder why and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Seems the ormlite using the microlog which I imported in other project. In the LoggerFactory, the comments say:

> It uses reflection to see what loggers are installed on the system and tries to find the most appropriate one.

I think that's why the ormlite does not uses the expected log output.

I solved this by change this behavior to the Android Log

```
System.setProperty(LoggerFactory.LOG_TYPE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, LoggerFactory.LogType.ANDROID.toString());
```

`System.setProperty("log.tag.ORMLite", "ERROR");`